# What books/websites should i read to learn to write readable and maintainable C code?

Tags: c, readability, maintainability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
>   [Good open source code for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324169/good-open-source-code-for-c)

I started learning C++ over 2 years ago.  Since then, i went back and learned C, among other programming languages, but C is my favorite.  While looking at open-source projects recently, i quickly realized that my code is ugly, barely readable, and the opposite of extendable.  I want this to change.  Any references/links to any books, websites, or other resources that would better help me program in C more professionally would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: See [Pointers on C](http://www.amazon.com/Pointers-C-Kenneth-Reek/dp/0673999866), its old, but I think this book taught me more than any other book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm you say you know C but it's not bad to mention the definite guide which is Dennis Ritchie's own book [The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628).  Another book I have heard good things about is [Programming in C](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=Programming%20C&x=0&y=0) by Stephen G Kochan, even though I have not read it myself.

But in my opinion the best way to actually learn to write optimal code is to try it. Make many projects, and fail at doing so. Then be forced to search the net for what made you fail or what a bug might be, realize that you wasted 2 days over a bug that could have been avoided if you had followed some programming standards and then learn from that experience